# Angular Material Datepicker | Lazy Loading + CustomDateAdapter + Internationalization - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, lazy-loading, ngx-translate

## Structure Question

I'm not quite sure If I found the right place for this 2 code lines:

```
providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'de-DE' },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, Platform] }
  ]
```

Currently they are in my material.module => which is imported in shared.module
=> which is imported in app.module and every lazy loaded module.

CustomDateAdapter:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
    subscription: any;

    format(date: Date, displayFormat?: string | Object): string {
        if (!this.subscription) {
            this.subscription = appLocale.subscribe(v => {
                this.setLocale(v);
            })
        }
        return super.format(date, displayFormat);
    }
}
```

the appLocal is in my translation Service:

```
export const appLocale: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('de');
```

(I found this code working here: [Blitz](https://angular-6vupnn.stackblitz.io))

My situation is - I have a datepicker and I can switch language between three languages without reloading the site.

My problem - I have a global service for translation - so it's not like in the stackblitz above that I'm changing language in the component because this is a dropdown in the app.component. As I import material in app.module and lazy loaded module (where the datepicker is) this couldn't work because I had two instances of CustomDateAdapter and just changed the app.component one. (I hope I understood this import/export/providers stuff right..)

I think I fixed that with the BehaviorSubject and the subscription.. but is this the right way to do this? I just want to register the two providers one time globally.

## Error Question

Sorry for the long structure question as it is acutally working. Unfortunately I'm getting this error.

```
osp-error-handler.ts:12 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at BehaviorSubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:51)
    at BehaviorSubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subject.js.Subject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:102)
    at BehaviorSubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:30)
    at CustomDateAdapter.push../src/app/shared/plugins/material/mat-datepicker.ts.CustomDateAdapter.format (mat-datepicker.ts:40)
    at MatDatepickerInput.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/datepicker.es5.js.MatDatepickerInput._formatValue (datepicker.es5.js:3259)
    at MatDatepickerInput.set [as value] (datepicker.es5.js:2961)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (datepicker.es5.js:2900)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:134)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
```

The error just happens first time I open the page with the datepickers. When I change the date or switching route it doesn't happen again. I think there is something wrong with:

```
 return super.format(date, displayFormat);
```

I hope someone can help :)

## Edit 1 - error fixed:

Changed the format function to:

```
    format(date: Date, displayFormat?: string | Object): string {
        let loc = appLocale.getValue();
        if (this.locale !== loc)
            this.setLocale(loc);
        return super.format(date, displayFormat);
    }
```

Thanks to Sergey leading me into the right direction. If you subscribe to an BehaviorSubject you will get a lot of change calls (even if it is the same value -don't exactly know why). As it is not working without the if I think If you call setLocale the format func gets called again because of a change trigger inside - so you would never get out of this..

Comment: It looks like you have defined somewhere handlers on value change which change the value (i.e. you want to modify the incoming value in valueChanges listener or similar). This happens in circle thus causing such an issue.

Comment: Try to remove subscription from your adapter. I guess that it may work incorrectly.

Comment: But I need the subscribe to change locale of the current adapter?

Comment: I added a console log in the subscribe => yeah it get called several times till the error appears..

Comment: Therefore you have to chose another approach. It doesn't seem to be working with observables. As far as I remember there is `adapter.use` or very similar to change the locale.

Comment: Have a look at https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples at the bottom of the `API` tab where "Datepicker with different locale" you can see there how to change locale at runtime.

Comment: Yes, I read that before but they don't change the locale from another service and without lazy loading. As I said - I don't want to switch language in every component - should work globally.

I think I got it working - I will post an answer.

Comment: Would be nice. I had to use module-level locale init in my app due to issue with Lazy Load

Comment: Cool! But also it would be better fit into the answer rather than question so that it's more obvious for newcomers.